# jOpenDocument Sheet.getValueAt(int, int) return value is both a String and a BigDecimal?

Tags: java, spreadsheet, classcastexception, bigdecimal, odf

I'm processing a .ods spreadsheet with the jOpenDocument library. Since I was processing strings, everything was ok, but when it comes to process numbers it's a pain.

In my code I iterate the spreadsheet and make some computations based on the value assumed by the cell at index x,y. Surprisingly enough, I can't get the class of the values I get:

```
BigDecimal ferialestringa;
     while (true) {
                        boolean duplicate = false;
                        value = (String) sheet.getValueAt(0, count);
                        System.out.println(sheet.getValueAt(5, count).getClass());
                        ferialestringa = (BigDecimal) sheet.getValueAt(5, count);
```

This snippet prints out:

```
class java.math.BigDecimal
class java.lang.String
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal
    at InspectTwitter.main(InspectTwitter.java:78)
```

You can see that the value appears to belong to two different classes.

If I try to parse the returned object to a string, I get also another ClassCastException:

```
class java.math.BigDecimal
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at InspectTwitter.main(InspectTwitter.java:78)
```

Note that this time the class seems to be just BigDecimal.

I tried to find documentation but only Sheet.getValueAt(String) is available on [this](http://www.jopendocument.org/docs/index.html) javadoc. (I've found this method in tutorials though, and it seems to be working very well on strings). What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

How is the original SpreadSheet created? Do you read it from a file?

A workaround could be:

```
ferialestringa = new BigDecimal(sheet.getCellAt(5, count).getTextValue());
```

This way you read the String value of the cell and then parse it to a BigDecimal